# Perl module loading - Safeguarding against: perhaps you forgot to load "Bla"?

Tags: perl, perl-module

When you run `perl -e "Bla->new"`, you get this well-known error:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Bla"
(perhaps you forgot to load "Bla"?)
```

Happened in a Perl server process the other day due to an oversight of mine. There are multiple scripts, and most of them have the proper `use` statements in place. But there was one script that was doing `Bla->new` in `sub blub` at line 123 but missing a `use Bla` at the top, and when it was hit by a click without any of the other scripts using `Bla` having been loaded by the server process before, then bang!

Testing the script in isolation would be the obvious way to safeguard against this particular mistake, but alas the code is dependent upon a humungous environment. Do you know of another way to safeguard against this oversight?

Here's one example how `PPI` (despite its merits) is limited in its view on Perl:

```
use strict;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $req = GET 'http://www.example.com';
$req->headers->push_header( Bla => time );

my $au=Auweia->new;

__END__
PPI::Token::Symbol          '$req'
PPI::Token::Operator        '->'
PPI::Token::Word            'headers'
PPI::Token::Operator        '->'
PPI::Token::Word            'push_header'

PPI::Token::Symbol          '$au'
PPI::Token::Operator        '='
PPI::Token::Word            'Auweia'
PPI::Token::Operator        '->'
PPI::Token::Word            'new'
```

Setting the header and assigning the `Auweia->new` parse the same. So I'm not sure how you can build upon such a shaky foundation. I think the problem is that `Auweia` could also be a subroutine; `perl.exe` cannot tell until runtime.

**Further Update**

Okay, from @Schwern's instructive comments below I learnt that `PPI` is just a tokenizer, and you *can* build upon it if you accept its limitations.

Comment: I wonder if perlcritic has a policy that helps with that.

Comment: @Lumi PPI is tokenizing correctly.  It's not shaky, but it is just a tokenizer.  You have to supply the meaning.  I'll update my answer to handle this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Testing is the only answer worth the effort.  If the code contains mistakes like forgetting to load a class, it probably contains other mistakes.  Whatever the obstacles, make it testable.  Otherwise you're patching a sieve.

That said, you have two options.  You can use [Class::Autouse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aAutouse) which will try to load a module if it isn't already loaded.  It's handy, but because it affects the entire process it can have unintended effects.

Or you can use [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PPI) to scan your code and find all the class method calls.  [PPI::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PPI%3a%3aDumper) is very handy to understand how PPI sees Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI;
use PPI::Dumper;

my $file = shift;
my $doc = PPI::Document->new($file);

# How PPI sees a class method call.
#    PPI::Token::Word      'Class'
#    PPI::Token::Operator  '->'
#    PPI::Token::Word      'method'
$doc->find( sub {
    my($node, $class) = @_;

    # First we want a word
    return 0 unless $class->isa("PPI::Token::Word");

    # It's not a class, it's actually a method call.
    return 0 if $class->method_call;

    my $class_name = $class->literal;

    # Next to it is a -> operator
    my $op = $class->snext_sibling or return 0;
    return 0 unless $op->isa("PPI::Token::Operator") and $op->content eq '->';

    # And then another word which PPI identifies as a method call.
    my $method = $op->snext_sibling or return 0;
    return 0 unless $method->isa("PPI::Token::Word") and $method->method_call;

    my $method_name = $method->literal;

    printf "$class->$method_name seen at %s line %d.\n", $file, $class->line_number;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. PPI appears limited in its view on Perl. (Going to update my question to show how.) Yes, I absolutely agree, testing is the way to go; alas, the complexity of the code, the rules on how it is to be organized make testing a difficult endeavour; they actually prevent it from being tested properly. Going to look at Class::Autouse, too.

Comment: @Lumi I've updated it to defend against `$obj->method1->method2`.  Unfortunately, there is no way to tell whether `Thing->method` is `Thing()->method` or `Thing::->method` without running code, something we're aware of.  You can add a check to see if you have a module called `Thing` installed.  For your purposes, if your linter finds an instance which is actually a subroutine call, modify the code to do `Thing()->method` to resolve the ambiguity.  Perl is full of these ambiguities, which is why PPI is just a tokenizer and why static analysis will only go so far.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what server enviroment you're running under, but from what you say it sounds like you could do with preloading all your modules in advance before executing any individual pages.  Not only would this prevent the problems you're describing (where every script has to remember to load all the modules it uses) but it would also save you memory.

In pre-forking servers (as is commonly used with mod_perl and Apache) you really want to load as much of your code *before* your server forks for the first time so that the code is stored once in copy-on-write shared memory rather than mulitple times in each child process when it is loaded on demand.

For information on pre-loading in Apache, see the section of [Practical mod_perl](http://modperlbook.org/html/10-1-3-Preloading-Perl-Modules-at-Server-Startup.html)

Comment: Thanks, Mark. It's a custom server architecture, with custom shortcomings. Hence most of the custom problems.