# i have an error in website Eprints, cannot send test email in perl

Tags: perl, sockets, sendmail

Connect failed :IO::Socket::INET: connect: timeout
at /usr/share/perl5/Net/SMTP/TLS.pm line 109.
here my code at 109

```
sub new {
    my $pkg = shift;
    my $host= shift;
    my %args= @_;
    $args{Host} = $host;
    $args{Hello}= "localhost" if not $args{Hello};
    # make the non-SSL socket that will later be
    # transformed
    $args{sock} = new IO::Socket::INET(
        PeerAddr    =>  $host,
        PeerPort    =>  $args{Port} || 25,
        Proto       =>  'tcp',
        Timeout     =>  $args{Timeout} || 5)
            or croak "Connect failed :$@\n";
```

Comment: Please post a complete and minimal example of a program that shows the problem. We don't know your inputs, and so on.

Comment: here my first error:
can't locate object method "new" via package "Net::SMTP::TLS" (perhaps you forgot to load "Net::SMTP::TLS"?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031386/perl-module-loading-safeguarding-against-perhaps-you-forgot-to-load-bla

Answer (score 0):

Your outgoing connections to port 25 may be blocked (firewalled) to prevent outgoing spam.

Do you get smtp greeting message when you telnet smtp port on the host from command line?

```
telnet hostname.domainname 25
```

Does the smtp server handle MSP (587) port?  [port for message submission via smtp protocol]

Comment: no, i have been strugling for 3 months of this error.